# Android: Database Insert within onReceive is called immediatly when setting up the BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, database, sqlite

When starting my app for the first time, i set up a Broadcast. The Broadcast is supposed to be repeating, but for test purposes i set it to setExact and call it everytime the app is started. The onReceive method does multiple things and it does them at the correct time. But the method within onReceive, which adds a new row to a Database is called immediatly when i register the Broadcast (before its triggered) and i cant figure out why. So everytime i start the app, it makes a new Entry and everytime onReceive gets called, it makes another (the correct) entry.

I call this method to set up the BroadcastReceiver when starting the app. I add +1 to Day if the time is in the past, so it then calls on the next day.

```
 public void startDayCheckOnce() {

    registerReceiver(new DayCheckReceiver(), new IntentFilter(DAY_CHECK_RECEIVER));
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    dayCheckIntent = new Intent(DAY_CHECK_RECEIVER);
    sendBroadcast(dayCheckIntent);

    dayCheckAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2000000000, dayCheckIntent, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
    if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    //TODO: SET BACK TO SETREPEATING
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), dayCheckAlarmIntent);

    dayCheckStarted = true;
    saveDayCheckStarted();
}
```

And this is the BroadcastReceiver. Everything gets called on the correct time, only

```
mDbHelper.addDayCheck()
```

gets called immediatly at the start of the app:

```
public class DayCheckReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (null != intent && DAY_CHECK_RECEIVER.equals(intent.getAction())) {


            //load TaskList
            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = sharedPrefs.getString(TASKLIST_FILE, null);
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<TaskItem>>() {
            }.getType();
            mTaskList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

            //modifications && writing to database
            if (mTaskList != null && mTaskList.size() > 0) {
                DatabaseHelper mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String date = df.format(c.getTime());
                String millisIdentifier;
                int doneState;

                for (int i = 0; i < mTaskList.size(); i++) {
                    millisIdentifier = mTaskList.get(i).getMilliIdentifier();
                    doneState = mTaskList.get(i).getDoneTodayValue();

                    mDbHelper.addDayCheck(millisIdentifier, date, doneState);

                    mTaskList.get(i).shiftDayChecks();
                    mTaskList.get(i).resetTimeLeft();
                }
            }


            //save TaskList
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
            gson = new Gson();
            json = gson.toJson(mTaskList);
            editor.putString(TASKLIST_FILE, json);
            editor.apply();

            //refresh Fragments
            if (tasksFragment.isVisible()) {
                FragmentTransaction refreshFT = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                refreshFT.detach(tasksFragment);
                refreshFT.attach(tasksFragment);
                refreshFT.commit();
            } else if (timerFragment.isVisible()) {
                timerFragment.refreshUI();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

And this is the dayCheck method itself:

```
public void addDayCheck(String millisIdentifier, String date, int doneState){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_DATE, date);
    values.put(COLUMN_DONE_STATE, doneState);

    db.insert(millisIdentifier, null, values);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, the reason seems to be "sendBroadcast(dayCheckIntent)". I built that according to a tutorial and mustve done something wrong because this method apparently calls the broadcast instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i actually found the mistake. I called "sendBroadcast(dayCheckIntent) when setting up the Broadcast, and this called onReceive instantly. It seems like a simple mistake, but due to intersection if different other things, it seemed like onReceive was only called once, but actually that wasnt the case.